# Create a file of a specific size with random printable strings in bash

Tags: string, bash, random

I want to create a file of a specific size containing only printable strings in bash.

My first thought was to use `/dev/urandom`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/file bs=1M count=100
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 10,3641 s, 10,1 MB/s

file /tmp/file && du -h /tmp/file
  /tmp/file: data
  101M  /tmp/file
```

This leaves me with a file, of my desired size, but not only containing printable strings.

Now, I can use `strings` to create a file only containing printable strings.

```
cat /tmp/file | strings > /tmp/file.txt
file /tmp/file.txt && du -h /tmp/file.txt 
  /tmp/file.txt: ASCII text
  7,0M  /tmp/file.txt
```

This leaves me with a file containing only printable strings, but with the wrong file size.

TL;DR

How can I create a file of a specific size, containing only printable strings, in bash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way is to use a transformation like base64 to convert the random bytes to characters. That will not erase any of the randomness from the source, it will only convert it to some other form.
For a (a little bit bigger) file of 1 MegaByte of size:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=786438 count=1 | base64 > /tmp/file
```

The resulting file will contain characters in the range `A–Za–z0–9` and `+/=`.

Below is the reason for the file to be a little bigger, and a solution.

You could add a filter to translate from that list to some other list (of the same size or less) with tr.

```
cat /tmp/file | tr 'A-Za-z0-9+/=' 'a-z0-9A-Z$%'
```

I have left the `=` outside of the translation because for an uniform random distribution it is better to leave out the last characters that will (almost) allways be `=`.

## Size

The size of the file will get expanded from the original size used from /dev/random in a factor of `4/3`. That is because we are transforming 256 byte values into 64 different characters. That is done by taking 6 bits from the stream of bytes to encode each character. When 4 characters have been encoded (6*4=24 bits) only three bytes have been consumed (8*3=24).

So, we need a count of bytes multiple of 3 to get an exact result, and multiple of 4 because we will have to divide by that.
We can not get a random file of exactly 1024 bytes (1k) or 1024*1024 = 1,048,576 bytes (1M) because both are not exact multiple of 3. But we can produce a file a little bigger and truncate it (if such precision is needed):

```
wanted_size=$((1024*1024))
file_size=$(( ((wanted_size/12)+1)*12 ))
read_size=$((file_size*3/4))

echo "wanted=$wanted_size file=$file_size read=$read_size"

dd if=/dev/urandom bs=$read_size count=1 | base64 > /tmp/file

truncate -s "$wanted_size" /tmp/file
```

The last step to truncate to the exact value is optional.

## Randomness generation.

As you are going to extract so much random values from urandom, please do not use `random` (use urandom) or your app will be blocked for a long time and the rest of the computer will work without randomness.

I'll recommend that you install the package haveged:

> haveged uses HAVEGE (HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and Expansion)
>   to maintain a 1M pool of random bytes used to fill /dev/random
>   whenever the supply of random bits in dev/random falls below the low
>   water mark of the device.

If that is possible.

Comment: @farhad Ok, the answer is complete now, please review it.

Answer (score 2):

A conversion of [@MarekNowaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927708/6843677)
answer to plain bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
(( $# )) || {  echo "Pass file size as initial parameter" >&2; exit 1; }
size=$1
mk_range(){ name=$1; shift; printf -v "$name" '%b' "$(printf '\\U%08x' "$@")"; }
add_chars(){ local var; mk_range var "$@"; chars+=$var; }
    ## uncomment following lines to use each range.
    add_chars {48..57}    # 0-9 numbers
    add_chars {65..90}    # A-Z LETTERS
    add_chars {97..122}   # a-z letters
    add_chars {32,{33..47},{58..64},{91..96},{123..127}}     # other chars.
    # convert list of characters to an array of characters.
    [[ $chars =~ ${chars//?/(.)} ]] && arr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}");
    alphabet_len=${#arr[@]} 
    # loop to print random characters
    for ((i=0;i<$size;i++)); do
        idx=$((RANDOM%alphabet_len))
        printf '%s' "${arr[idx]}"
    done
    # Add a trailing new line.
    echo
```

This code does not ensure that the resulting random distribution is uniform, it was written as an example. To ensure a random distribution in the output, 
we would have to use careful arbitrary precision arithmetic to change the base (count of output characters).
Also, RANDOM is not a CSPRNG.

Comment: Nice one :), but unfortunately it doesn't work on Win (MINGW). Some issues with bash syntax on that environment, and no `random` tool, at default.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
size=1048576 # 1MB
fname="strings.txt"

while read line ; do
    # Append strings to the file ...
    strings <<< "${line}" >> "${fname}"
    fsize="$(du -b "${fname}" | awk '{print $1}')"
    # ... until it is bigger than the desired size
    if [ ${fsize} -gt ${size} ] ; then
        # Now truncate the file to the desired size and exit the loop
        truncate -s "${size}" strings.txt
        break
    fi 
done < /dev/urandom
```

I admit that it is not very efficient. I faster attempt would be to use `dd`:

```
size=1048576
fname="strings.txt"

truncate -s0 "${fname}"

while true ; do
    dd if=/dev/urandom bs="${size}" count=1 | strings >> "${fname}"
    fsize="$(du -b "${fname}" | awk '{print $1}')"
    if [ ${fsize} -gt ${size} ] ; then
        truncate -s "${size}" strings.txt
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1 While this gets the job done, it is quite inefficient because a lot of bytes will be rejected by the command `strings`. It would be better if all bytes could be used in the output with some transformation. Please read my answer.

Comment: Sure, however `base64` reduces the randomness. But I'm not sure if that matters here. Another point I would raise is that you are creating only one large string instead of multiple random strings. I understood the question like that

Comment: No, base64 maintains the randomness. Is like writing 0x83 or decimal 131, one use two digits the other three, but both represent the same number. Like binary `10000011` also represent decimal `131`. Just different representations of the same value, a completely loss-free  transformation. Not wasting time or effort in calculating something that will be thrown away is always relevant, I believe.

Comment: The string command will select the characters that seem text inside a file, that is not the same as asking for strings with a newline. But that could be added easily to the script by using an (also lossless) transformation with tr to include a new line character in the range printed.

Comment: In fact the strings command will only select strings of 4 of more consecutive printable characters and trow the rest away.

Comment: What I want to say is that base64 has a limited character set. Not all printable characters are part of base64. That reduces the randomness. I've used the `strings` command only because the OP mentioned it in the question. Actually it would have been better if the OP would have stated what

Comment: Randomness, or better said, count of options, is a function of the number of charaters per position **and** of number of positions. In specific, it is `r=n**l`, where `n` is the number of characters per position and `l` is the length in number of character positions. That's why a computer, which works in binary (only 1's and 0's), could represent much larger randomness/entropy.  A base64 encoded text has less characters *per position* than a random byte of range 0-256, but base64 is longer (use more character positions) than the byte values from which it is transformed (in a relation of 4/3).

Comment: Sure, but the length is a constant here. It's the final size of the file.

Comment: Yes, sure, but the difference between 64 or 98 (if you include new line and tab) is not that big. You get nice and valid "passwords" anyway. If the count of characters is very important, you could take a look at [basE91](http://base91.sourceforge.net/) or [b85](https://sites.google.com/site/dannychouinard/Home/unix-linux-trinkets/little-utilities/base64-and-base85-encoding-awk-scripts) or even [Radix-95](http://www.tapr.org/~wd5ivd/Radix_95_Thesis.pdf). ... ... Next ...

Comment: ... Follow... But it is very easy to fail to keep the output as an uniform random distribution. To do that, careful arbitrary precision arithmetic for base change divisions have to be used. In short, keeping with the mantra of Unix: for applications "do one thing, do it well". And for the users: "Use the tools available". It seems better to use the very common base64 encoding, That ensure an uniform random distribution (no error). And, if the specific list of characters doesn't fit an specific use case: change it with tr (already explained in the answer). But hey!: roll your own code.

Comment: Hey, you seem to have a very funded knowledge of this problem. I really don't claim that for me. If the question would be: "I want to generate good passwords" I would not have answered. Doing the math right is really important in that case. I just found it interesting to create a random, printable, file of a specific size with command line tools. The approach I've showed is pretty hackish and nothing to be proud of, for various reasons. I admit that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in awk way and customize character set.

This solution is dedicated for Windows bash users - `MINGW`, because there is no `dd`, `random` tools at default `MINGW` environment.

*random_readable.sh* Bash script that randomize N characters from defined alphabet:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Pass file size as initial parameter"
    exit
fi

SIZE=$1
seed=$( date +%s )

awk -v size="$SIZE" -v seed="$seed" '
# add characters from range (a .. b) to alphabet
function add_range(a,b){
    idx=a;
    while (idx <= b) {
        alphabet[idx] = sprintf("%c",idx)
        idx+=1
    }
}
BEGIN{
    srand(seed);  
    NUM=size;  
    idx=0;  

    # creating alfphabet dictionary
    add_range(32,126)   # all printable
    ## uncomment following lines to random [a-zA-Z0-9<operators>]
    # add_range(48,57)    # numbers
    # add_range(65,90)    # LETTERS
    # add_range(97,122)   # letters
    # add_range(33,47)    # operators: !"# .. etc

    # alfphabet to alphanums array
    idx=0
    for (k in alphabet){
        alphanums[idx]=alphabet[k]
        idx+=1
    }
    alphabet_len = idx
    i=0

    # and iterate to random some characters
    idx =0
    while (idx < NUM){                         
        dec =0
        char_idx=int(rand() * alphabet_len)
        char = alphanums[char_idx]
        printf("%s",alphanums[char_idx])
        idx+=1
    }  
}  
'
```

Creating file:

```
random_readable.sh 100 > output.txt
```

Comment: I guess you were missing to print the newline, right?

Comment: hek2mgl - no, I do not, because the purpose was to save the output of that script to file. With new line char, the file would be +1 byte oversized.

Comment: Ok, sure. But you could simply use newline instead of whitespace in your character list. But that doesn't matter too much. Good answer

Comment: Just for fun, I [converted your script to plain bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40930007/6843677).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

1. `truncate`
   You should have a baseline textfile with a size larger than what you need.
   then use the following:

   ```
   truncate -s 5M filename
   DESCRIPTION
      Shrink or extend the size of each FILE to the specified size

   [...]

    -s, --size=SIZE
         set or adjust the file size by SIZE
   ```

2.Use `tail`: this options requires reference text file too.

```
tail -c 1MB reference_big.txt> 1mb.txt
```

Comment: That would mean that I have to, considering the file sizes mentioned in the question, create a random non-string file of about 1.45GB first, correct?

Comment: random string file of 1.45GB

Answer (score 0):

### Quick [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution

Based on your request, using `string` on `urandom`

```
dd if=<(strings </dev/urandom) bs=4K count=25600 of=/tmp/file
```

.. or maybe *better* (this avoid *newline* and by using `tr` do require less *random generated bytes*):

```
dd bs=4K count=25600 if=/dev/urandom |
    tr \\000-\\037\\177-\\377 \\040-\\077\\040-\\077\\040-\\150 >/tmp/file
```

### Demo:

On a standard 80 chars width terminal:

```
dd bs=$COLUMNS count=5 if=<(
  tr \\000-\\037\\177-\\377 \\040-\\077\\040-\\077\\040-\\150 </dev/urandom )
<h<&9.[,&> p)hMp8)s 8|S5&Q 1hD9:b7o"B$%hDc99@h8C!9uflMwu)hFZ($h:& Tl a,X1s?&29n(
h.7\)h`- X24Tq-9g6hvaVqh]E"/vRK30=.L-J&9*/ZFMz<@%h$;cN[&Xu4hJ ?1:-"II+SQD$\h;h$M
f0}7'7i"*m*d$CFAn/X%<c'] h;}?Oe4d?pFP<f+i0:ohh3dUC5m4_*F!d`#I,4)99*42hVh8A#a8 .6
/~.g3!Vd>h8h>6=h_`A:ha/8ZHVY{QIh4?/Mc]#&b&*h*t6V#=:j9$\-6#ERr8]-Y]U?*\h4+m37c841
8rh#?58;)4'X4Ghh4Z :h7h#!6hhh?"8\$$U/"@ek,N)?;MJ(>(uh\_^I41+080;h2!S#)04(Dhnh"%h
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
400 bytes copied, 0.0005598 s, 715 kB/s
```

Here are exactly **`400`** printable characters (whithout any *newline*).

Comment: I like that. I didn't know that `if=<(strings </dev/urandom)` was even possible!

Comment: In 1st, you have to generate more random and trash non ascii, Second will transform all byte to a printable character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 > filename.txt
```

with
`tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'` is the characterset
`fold -w 32` is the length and
`head -n 1` is the number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Combining a couple ideas here, this one-liner works for me:

```
dd if=<(base64 < /dev/urandom) of=tmpfile bs=1K count=102400
```

For more control of the output (but slower performance) use `tr`:

```
dd if=<(tr -dc '[a-zA-Z0-9]' < /dev/urandom) of=tmpfile bs=2K count=51200
```

Note that these only appear to work with block sizes of up to around 2K on macOS Monterey and ~5K on debian buster (not sure why); larger block sizes  result in smaller than expected files.